# TDD in Objective-c: property/constructor injection or method swizzling?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

Since I've started using TDD I've been firmly convinced that it's a great way to write good correct pattern compliant code, without forcing my design decisions.
And I found this true in 80% scenarios, but I have problems when it comes to test certain tipe of objects which, for some reason, wrap and hide an object inside the implementation.

To give you an example let's think of a **MyLocationManager** objects which gives a common interface to my objects to be used, and wraps inside an **NSLocationManager**. 
When I want to test such an object I have to supply a mock NSLocationManager of course.

I have of course the property/constructor injection method, but this means adding a property, or a constructor parameter, with an objects that I simply want to hide from the other objects: I've created **MyLocationManager** to wrap and hide **NSLocationManager**, why should I be exposing a property just to test it?

A method I've found which is pretty straightforward is to method swizzle **NSLocationManager**'s methods, so I can exchange the actual implementation of a method with a mock one, but this seems pretty unclean and I don't know how safe it is.

As far as I can understand, there might be a Demeter Law's violation in not exposing a property constructor, but on the other hand, I think that in objective-c some flexibility on this pattern is accepted.

So my question is, there should be any way I'm not clearly seeing to adopt property/constructor injection, or method swizzling is a commonly used practice?

Are there any other techniques for this scenario adopted that I should better use?

On a footnote: 
This problem is true even with objects that wraps networking code and classes like **NSUrlSession**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of Test Driven Development experience, I find this old question of mine pretty simple to answer.
For some reason I was thinking that property injection and dependency injection where to avoid to mask something.
I simply don't think this anymore.

In the previous scenario of my original question the right answer from present-me is:

You have to expose the dependency of NSLocationManager, maybe providing a constructor injector method, and a convenience constructor method, to initialise the location manager with NSLocationManager.
There is no real need to hide the dependency even if it is a wrapper class, because in the exact moment you find yourself with the need to swizzle some methods, you're hacking the "internals" of your object and tweaking it without testing the interface, modifying the runtime behaviour in an uncontrolled manner.

If you wanna swizzle, swizzle ahead, but it's not the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at one point the testing set-up can be more complicated than the code to test, so one might remember, what testing was invented for.

I think a pragmatic way is, to expose the property you need only in a separate header containing a separate class continuation.

Comment: How could this be possible without including this test header in production code?

Comment: I do not understand that question. You said "why should I be exposing a property just to test it?". It is production code with testing or without testing!?